# MVC 4 Remote Validation failing

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I am trying to implement Remote Validation and its failing to call the Action Method:

When I test in Firebug and am getting an error on the page that should be validating one of its fields. This is most likely the root cause of the remote validation not working.

My Scripts in _LayoutView

```
  <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/3.0/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

This is the error Error:

```
Syntax error, unrecognized expression: :input[name=UserReg.Password]
http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.0.min.js Line 2
```

I have tried jQuery 1.8.0 and the error is still there.

UserReg.Password is part of the View

```
   @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserReg.Password)
```

This is the rendered page source for that field:

```
     <input class="text-box single-line password" data-val="true" data-val-length="The Password must be at least 6 characters long." data-val-length-max="100" data-val-length-min="6" data-val-required="The Password field is required." id="UserReg_Password" name="UserReg.Password" type="password" value="" />
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The `jquery validate plugin` requires that a `input` `name` containing any special characters, "like dots", be enclosed in quotes when declared in a validation rule. `"UserReg.Password"`; if you can't do that, try a `name` without any special characters.

Comment: See:  http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Reference#Fields_with_complex_names_.28brackets.2C_dots.29

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery Validate plugin requires that an input name containing any special characters, "like dots", be enclosed in quotes when declared in a validation rule.

See: [docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/…](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Reference#Fields_with_complex_names_.28brackets.2C_dots.29)

> **Fields with complex names (brackets, dots)**
>
> "If your form consists of fields using names that aren't legal
>   JavaScript identifiers, you have to quote those names when using the
>   rules option:"

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myform').validate({
        rules: {
            "UserReg.Password": {
                // whatever your rules,
                // required: true
            }
        }
    });
});
```

If you can't do that, try switching this `input` to a name without any special characters.

---

**Side-note:**  You're including jQuery Validate v1.9.0.  However, even the latest version of the plugin, v1.10.0, has not been tested to work with jQuery 1.9.0.  You'll have to use the "pre-release" [Validate plugin version 1.11.0pre](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/blob/master/jquery.validate.js) from Github if you want to keep jQuery 1.9.0.

Answer (score 0):

I removed this script from the _LayoutView

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
```

and the problem went away. Client-side validation is still working.

Comment: Not sure how your client-side validation can possibly work without the validate plugin.  But the version you were using was not tested with jQuery 1.9.  Also, your `input` `attribute` name contained an illegal character that the plugin can't normally handle.  Remove the dot from the `name`.

Comment: It is not possible to remove the dot from the name. The Razor view engine emits the name and id of the element. Anyway client-side validation is definately working with the 1.9 script removed.

Comment: From what I remember, jQuery.validate and unobtrusive.validate are conflicting files. Both are based on the same base library, but unobtrusive.validate has additional behavior of it's own. My experience was that since they are similar, you will often get the expected result if you use css classes for declaring validation rules, but js declarations for the same validations will not work. I think remote validations should have the same issue. Also explains why removing jquery.validate fixed your problem.